# I am getting 502 Bad gateway error while creating team using Microsoft Graph Api and even using PowerShell commands

Tags: java, powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, powershell-cmdlet

I am getting 502 Bad gateway error while creating team using Microsoft Graph Api and even using PowerShell commands. What am I doing wrong?

**1.First attempt from Postman using Microsoft graph api**:

Attached is the screenshot of Postman console while I am trying to create a new team:

[image: Post Man console]

I had searched online but I haven't got any solution so I tried doing the same thing from PowerShell using Microsoft Teams PowerShell cmdlets but I am still getting the same error .

Here I am using the access token i got from application permissions and I also assigned the app "Helpdesk administrator" role

**2.Second attempt with Powershell cmdlets:-**

Here is the screenshot of output in PowerShell

[image: Powershell output]

I had logged in to Microsoft Teams as a global administrator.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you please confirm if the access token you are using has all the required permissions?

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Yeah it has  all the required permissions

Comment: Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: Yes @Gousia-MSFT

Comment: Could you please share the request being sent for this?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using the Microsoft beta api instead of the v.1.0?

The fact that you are using two different methods and getting a back-end error suggests either it is a problem with the beta api or possibly some error related to your account.

According to the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-beta

When creating a new team based on an existing group, the body should be in this format:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams
Content-Type: application/json
{
        "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('standard')",

        "group@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups('groupId')"
}
```

Your Postman screenshot has the "group@odata.bind" value as a slightly different format.  Try using the one above, and replace groupId with your actual group id.

Good luck.

Comment: I had tried using your suggestion and even after following the same body format there is no change in the error and the reason why i am using beta is because i would like to create the team from an existing group